# Cannot create proper new environment from text file in Anaconda navigator

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

It's ok when import text file for new environment in anaconda navigator but when created it says "**CondaEnvException:pip failed**". Then new environment misses some libraries and cannot install jupyter notebook.
text file includes:

````
lxml==4.5.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.3.2
notebook==6.0.3
numpy==1.18.1
openpyxl==3.0.4
pandas==1.1.2
Pillow==7.2.0
scikit-learn==0.23.2
scipy==1.4.1
seaborn==0.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18```
````